Git difftool with Beyond Compare shows identical files as different when using --dir-diff

I'm experiencing an issue when using Git's difftool command with Beyond Compare on macOS. When I run the following command:
git difftool --dir-diff HEAD^ HEAD
Beyond Compare opens successfully, but it's not showing the differences between commits as expected. Instead, it's comparing the files as if they were different files, even though they should be showing the actual differences between the two commits.

the files on the right side are symlinks, and apparently Beyond Compare is treating these as different beasts. Check if there is an option to say "for symlinks, compare the contents" somewhere.

git difftool -d basically creates two tmp directories with a copy of the files that need to be compared.
However, when it detects that a file in the second directory has the exact same content as the worktree file, git creates a symlink to your actual file rather than a copy for that file.
My understanding is: in that situation, when you edit the file through the diff viewer, you edit your actual file on disk, rather than a tmp copy that will get deleted when the command exits.
This can be turned off using --no-symlinks:
git difftool --no-symlinks -d HEAD~ HEAD

do note, however, that if you edit something there, every modification will be lost when you exit the diff viewer.

Aparently this doesn't suit Beyond Compare, who says "these two things are different" rather than allowing you to compare the two contents.
See if Beyond Compare has an option to deal with symlinks -- I would be surprised if it didn't.
Or use another diff viewer: I know that meld handles symlink just fine for example:
git difftool --tool=meld HEAD~ HEAD


To make Beyond Compare compare the symlink targets rather than the links themselves:

Click the Rules toolbar button (referee icon).
Go to the Handling tab.
Check Follow symbolic links.

To make the setting the default for all new comparisons, change the dropdown at the bottom of the dialog from Use for this view only to Also update session defaults before you click OK.
